# What does it mean to "unwrap" a reference_wrapper?

Tags: c++, boost, reference-wrapper

I am writing a utility class to "*unwrap*" a `std::reference_wrapper`, but I'm a bit conflicted as to what this means.

`boost::unwrap_reference<T>::type` is defined as `U` (where `T` is `std::reference_wrapper<U>`), but this seems counterintuitive. If a `reference_wrapper` is meant to "*wrap*" a reference, then I would expect an "*unwrapped*" `reference_wrapper` to *be a reference*.

Admittedly, this question may lead to opinion or conjecture, but is there any reason to prefer `U` over `U&` as the unwrapped `type` (aside from following the model of boost)? Are there any technical reports which detail `boost::unwrap_reference` that might provide a rationale for boost's model?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what difference it makes.

I suppose it's easier to add `&`-qualifier than to remove it with `std::remove_reference`?

In fact this is probably the reason: it's far easier to do further type combinations on bare type than dealing with const/volatile/ref qualification at all times. See e.g. this usage:

```
template<typename Class, typename TypeIn, typename TypeOut>
struct is_cnv<Class, TypeIn, TypeOut, typename enable_if<is_class<Class>, void>::type>
{
    typedef typename ::boost::unwrap_reference<Class>::type class_type;
    typedef void signature_type(TypeIn const&, optional<TypeOut>&);

    BOOST_DECLARE_IS_CALLABLE(is_callable, operator());

    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value = (is_callable<class_type, signature_type>::value));
};
```

(that's in `convert/detail/is_converter.hpp`, one of the few places that actually uses the `unwrap_reference` trait from `boost/core/ref.hpp`)

Because we know `class_type` is not ref-qualified, it's easier to feed it into `is_callable` and not get surprised.

Comment: Your reasoning does make sense. The way I was using the utility class depended on it returning a reference type, but I can actually just avoid the utility class altogether.